# What are the current requirements to get a visa to Thailand in Vientiane (Laos)?

Tags: visas, thailand, laos, vientiane

I have a Swedish passport. I recently entered Thailand from Laos and was allowed to stay visa free for 30 days. I am currently still in Thailand and planning to go to Vientiane within a few days when my 30 days expire. I do not have any previous visas at all to Thailand in this passport.

What are the requirements to get a 60 day tourist visa to Thailand in Vientiane this time?

I was in Thailand a few years ago so I need to know if anything has changed.

Someone mentioned that it is required to show a proof of funds of 20000 THB now, is that correct? (It was never the case when I used to live in Thailand before).

Looking for an updated list of current requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a new visa but could get a visa extension:

> your 30 day visa exempt entry at immigration for a fee of 1900 baht.
>   In Vientiane you only need the application form with 2 photos attached, copy for your passport photo page and Lao entry stamp. Plus 1000 baht for the fee.

(From [this forum](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1074875-what-are-the-current-requirements-to-get-a-visa-to-thailand-in-vientiane-laos/), also asked concerning a Swedish passport)

Looks like it’s the same question as you posted here.

Also verified from this source:

> Those who arrive at the airport without a prior visa will continue to receive a 30-day stamp up to 6 times per calendar year. Extensions at Thai Immigration for the visa exemption stamps remain to be 30 days for a fee of 1,900 baht.

(Also verified on [this website](https://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand/new-visa-rules.php))